# I am trying to bind a click event after setting a class dynamically

Tags: jquery

I built a custom dropdown box using a divs and I want to bind a `click` event to the opened class. Here is a basic example. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/X874X/5/).

the problem is that if I click the test div after clicking the wrapper div, it is firing both click events.

I am basically just trying to bind an a click event to the body after the first click event.
Sorry guys the linker stripped the last part of my fiddle url.

Comment: Delegation my friend... try `$('#element').on('click', function(){...`

Comment: @Alvaro you have put an additional . after on

Comment: I've tried several different delegations on the one function. It works as expected until you click the #test div, then it fires the #test click and the .close click;

Comment: @user2932725 what is your desired output? it clicks, you have no "close" class

Comment: Well I basically want to remove a class with a body click. I open a div, then i want to attach an onclick to the body to run once that will remove the class to "close" the div.

Comment: i have tested the jsfiddle and have found that it is the second on(click that isn't working. if you combine it into the first onclick as per the bottom of my post it works

Comment: I managed to solve the issue. I had e.stopPropagation() on the wrapper instead of the div inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. I had e.stopPropagation() on the wrapper instead of the div inside.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

the function needs to go like this

```
$(document).on("click", "#someid", function (e) {

});
```

this is what i changed the js to in the fiddle if you wish to try

```
    $(function(){
    $("body").one("click", "#test", function(){
        $(this).addClass("close");
        alert("Close Class Added");
    });
    $("body").one("click", ".close", function(){
        $(this).removeClass("close");
        alert("Closed");
    });
});
```

The second .one class eliminates the need for an if statement as you don't need to check if .close has been added has it will only trigger if the class is set

Comment: problem is when i click on the div, i add the class "close". After that i want to use the .one function. I only want 1 click event on the body to remove the class.

Comment: @eg_dac so you want one class that adds the class if it's the first thing that is clicked on the website? Am i right in thinking that? I've updated my post above to reflect what i think you mean.

Comment: @eg_dac sorry i meant only clicked once not first thing that is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your fiddle:

```
$("body").on("click", "#test", function(e){
    alert("click1");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#test").addClass("close");
});

$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if($("#test").hasClass("close")){
        alert("click2");
    }
});
```

I think that should do what you want.